# $f:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous, then if $\int_0^x |f(t)| \ dt = \int_x^2 |f(t)| \ dt$ then $f(x) = 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I have that

$f:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous, then if $\int_0^x |f(t)| \ dt = \int_x^2 |f(t)| \ dt$, $f(x) = 0$ for $x\in [0,2]$

I tried to substitute $x=0$ in the equality to get:

$$0 = \int_0^0 |f(t)| \ dt = \int_0^2 |f(t)| \ dt$$

So we have that $$\int_0^2 |f(t)| \ dt = 0$$

then $f(x) = 0$ because we're integrating something that's always positive or $0$.

Am I right?

Comment: More or less. Depends on how much rigor is expected in your solutions. Perhaps try to justify $$\int_0^2 |f| dx = 0 \implies f=0$$ a little more rigorously.

Comment: The condition is in fact more than what you used. If you apply the fundamental theorem of calculus, it seems that you can get an easier proof.

Comment: @DKS the riemann sum of something $0$ or positive is zero, so they all should be zero?

Answer (score 5):

For an alternative approach, using the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) and the given identity:

$$|f(x)| = \left(\int_0^x |f(t)|\;dt\right)' = \left(\int_x^2 |f(t)|\;dt\right)' = -|f(x)|$$

Therefore $\;\;|f(x)| = -|f(x)|$ $\;\;\implies\;\; |f(x)| = 0$ $\;\;\implies\;\; f(x) = 0\;\;$ for $\;\; x \in [0,2]$.

Answer (score 1):

Right so far.  To conclude, reason as follows.  Since $f(x)$ is continuous, so is $|f(x)|$. Therefore, if there existed a $x_* \in [0, 2]$ at which $|f(x_*)| > 0$, then (because of the said continuity) $x_*$ would have a neighborhood in which $|f| > $ some positive constant.  This, in turn, would imply
$$
\int_{0}^{2} |f(t)| \; dt > \int_{\mbox{that neighborhood}} |f(t)| \; dt > 0,
$$
a contradiction.